# Getting the database structure of my existing database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible that a database doesn't have database schema or information schema because I have an existing database, and i want to have the database structure of it. I can't able to get the structure of it

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME ='products';
```

It gives an error message that the

> `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` doesn't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION()`